# Как вставить изображение в запись но при этом не вставлять в галерею

Tags: wordpress

Нужно добавить изображение в запись, но так, что бы оно не добавлялось в галерею. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а какой смысл вы вкладываете в фразу "добавить изображение в запись"?

Comment: ну кнопка такая при добавлении медиафайла.

Comment: Когда я так делаю, то изображение добавляется в запись куда мне и надо. Но и добавляется в галерею, а это мне не нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img src="">` не?

Comment: типа какой вопрос такой и ответ )))))

Comment: нет, нужно обычным добавлением медиафайлов